# Creating bar chart in FastAPI

Tags: python, html, json, charts, fastapi

I want to create a simple bar chart for a specific key and its values in a json data in FastAPI. The data is as shown below. I want to make a chart where indexes are in the x-bar and values of Blue in the y-bar.

Can you please help me or lead me somewhere where I can learn that?

{"1": {"Red": 14, "Blue": 12}, "2": {"Red": 58, "Blue": 54}, "3": {"Red": 26, "Blue": 65}}